# r - Chart Excel-like Cell Highlights Similar to Autoformat

Tags: r, graph

If I have a dataframe like so:

```
            client_1    client_2    client_3
metric_1    0.49        0.01        0.11
metric_2    0.04        0.02        0.02
```

Is there a way I can add color to any value that is below the threshold .05 is highlighted in green so the output is like the image below?

[image: Basic Excel Highlighting]

Or even better - with some basic formatting such as:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps with a graph? There are multiple possibilities, but for a quick look this might help: image(as.matrix(df),zlim=c(5,13),col='yellow')? The white cells indicating values outside the defined range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `DT` library and `datatable` for formatting tables, in your first case, you can set the `cut` to be 0.05 and corresponding background color as the value with the `styleInterval`, take a look at [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) to see all options you can have with `DT`:

```
library(DT)
datatable(df) %>% 
    formatStyle(names(df), backgroundColor = styleInterval(0.05, c("lightgreen", "white")))
```

[image]

Comment: Seems legit, but I don't know how to print/display it. Any pointers so I can verify?

Comment: It can be saved as image or pdf from rStudio viewer or embedded in r markdown file, if this is what you mean with printing or displaying.